# Symfony 4 add service in container

Tags: symfony4

I use **csa_guzzle_bundle** with symfony 4, i have 2 clients in csa_guzzle.yaml for the moment, but it is possible that there are more in the future.
So, i want to call dynamically an csa_guzzle_client with the container `$this->get("csa_guzzle.clients.".$client");` it's work in symfony 3 but not in symfony 4 because autowiring.

my question is why to add service in container_bag for use with `$this->get('alias');`?

thanks for help

Comment: Your controller has to herit from Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller, not from AbstractController

Comment: thank you for help!, it's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank Thomas Lefetz, If you use any services no public with methode ->get(''). Inherit your controller from Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller, no AbstractController.